Python panda split column maintaining multiline in a row
I have data below and would like to split Desc to 2 columns. The text after special character to another column. Desc have non fixed multiline in a row.
================================
    It        |        Desc
================================
0   coat      |      Bos @Target@                                                                 
                     B2 @Sfop re@
1   boots     |      Wos (DSW)
================================

I am getting Columns must be same length as key error
import pandas as pd
# creating the df
item = ['coat','boots']
dec = ["Bos @Target@\n  B2 @Sfop re@", "Wos (DSW)"]
df = pd.DataFrame(item, columns=   ['It'])
df['Desc'] = dec
print(df)
df[["Desc", "Ret"]] =   df["Desc"].str.findall("\w+").apply(pd.Series)

Output needed
================================
    It      |    Desc    |    Ret
================================
0  coat     |    Bos     |   @Target@                                        
                 B2          @Sfop re@
1  boots    |    Wos     |   (DSW)
================================


df[['It']].join(df.Desc.str.split("\n").explode().str.split("(?=[@(])", n = 1, expand=True))??

You could use str.extractall to get the two parts:
df['Desc'].str.extractall(r'([^\n]+) ([@(][^\n]+)')

            0          1
  match                 
0 0       Bos   @Target@
  1        B2  @Sfop re@
1 0       Wos      (DSW)

Then, aggregate again with newlines as separators:
df[['Desc', 'Ret']] = (df['Desc'].str.extractall('([^\n]+) ([@(][^\n]+)')
                       .groupby(level=0).agg('\n'.join)
                       )

Output:
      It       Desc                  Ret
0   coat  Bos\n  B2  @Target@\n@Sfop re@
1  boots        Wos                (DSW)

Regex demo
